`rsync` do not iterate through sub-directories and files, if source and target directories have the same timestamp
Is it possible for rsync if directories:
/source_directory/dir-A and /target_directory/dir-A have the same modify timestamp, to not proceed checking their files and sub-directories?
I thing this will decrease a lot the time for the sync, as I sync an 20 TB disk to another and I change only a few files.
